# Datastax Opscenter Agent installation is broken re: log4j

Tags: cassandra, log4j

I am trying to install Opscenter, and datastax agent on our Cassandra cluster. When I start the datastax-agent, I am getting this error:

```
log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (org.eclipse.jetty.util.log).
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
log4j:WARN See http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/faq.html#noconfig for more info.
```

This URL has zero helpful configuration info for us non-Java programmers. We're using latest Opscenter, Cassandra 1.1, and Amazon Linux from within EC2 (Seems to be EL6).

Comment: That warning is harmless and can be ignored.  Are there other issues/errors you're seeing?

Comment: Confirmed, this message is not useful or helpful - a red herring.